# Is there a way to put socket.io events into functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, socket.io, functional-programming

I wanna encapsulate socket.io events into functions to make it more readable for my project, here is an example. I am trying to put this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
            //code
});
```

Into something like this:

```
function isThereANewConnection() {
 io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
        //..return true?
 });
}

function update() {
   if(isThereANewConnection()) {
    //do something with the socket data..
  }
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how i could implement this since i cannot return something from the function. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). This isn't the way callbacks usually work. The idea of "if there is a new connection" isn't something you encode in a conditional in synchronous flow, it's something that implicitly is true whenever the callback fires. In other words, just put your logic in the callback, no `if` needed. If `update` has to know information from the callback, the callback could mutate shared state that the `update` function could read when it runs, but without more context it's hard to recommend anything specific.

Comment: you do not need to put them in an update function as they are already event listeners. They handle the "update" process on their own

Comment: What is the REAL problem you're trying to solve here.  Your server should not be wanting to block on the next connection.  It should register an event handler for when any new connection arrives.  If you show us WHY you thought you wanted to do this, then we can better help you solve your actual problem (probably not going the direction you currently are because that's just not how you do multi-user event driven programming).

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes the problem is that i am trying to make an Object oriented multiplayer game, the game itself like player and input classes are object oriented. I was thinking to design my server class in such a way that it is OOP too and write al the logic in the update method for that specific class, just like the game. But i think i should handle the server architecture in a different way then?

Comment: Wrapping code into functions isn't an end in itself. A function must at least take and return a value, otherwise you are just abusing its interface. Using a composable event stream (async/push) to abstract from socket.io events makes more sense. You can either implement it as an Observable or as a stateless, lazy Promise (called Task in FP jargon).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really explained what you're trying to accomplish by putting "events into functions" so it's hard to know precisely what you want it to look like.

At it's heart, nodejs is an event driven environment.  As such, you register event listeners and they call you when there's an event.  That's the structure of the socket.io connection event.

If you don't want everything inline such as this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
            //code
});
```

You can put the event listener callback into a function itself such as:

```
io.on('connection', onConnection);
```

Then, somewhere else (either in the same module or imported into this module), you would define the `onConnection` function.

```
function onConnection(socket) {
    // put your code here to handle incoming socket.io connections
    socket.on('someMsg', someData => {
        // handle incoming message here
    });
}
```

Note: inline callback functions (of the type you seem to be asking to avoid) are very common in nodejs programming.  One of the reasons for using them is that when they are inline, they have available to them all the variables from the parent scope (without having to pass them all as arguments) and there are times this is very useful.  So, it might be a style that you will find useful rather than avoiding.

Comment: I am making an object oriented multiplyer game, the game itself is OOP structured like it has a update method for that specific class logic, I was thinking to  structure my server class in such a way that is it understandable and OOP but i think i should go for a diffrent approach for that, Thanks for your clear explanation :)

Comment: @ShaileshChotoe - Your question is very unclear and lacking details for what you want to do.  I will try to help you if you add more to your question that explains more about what you're trying to do.  If you want an OO design, then show the classes you plan to have and describe how you want socket.io events to fit into that.  As your question stands now, it doesn't describe any of that.  Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to structure your code in a way that is more readable and useful to you.  But if you did want this, you could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

```
async function getNewConnection() {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    io.on('connection', resolve);
  });
}
```

Then in your other code:

```
const socket = await getNewConnection();
```

Really though, for this connection handler you should stick with the callback pattern.  It keeps things simple for you.  Run your updates when the connection comes in, and not the other way around.

Comment: I think you meant to write `return new Promise(...)`? But this has another issue being that `io.on("connection", cb)` will fire its callback whenever there is a new socket connection, so it can execute multiple times. However, as a promise can only be resolved once, only the first socket connection will ever be obtained from your Promise and all the other socket connections won't do anything as the Promise has already resolved.

Comment: @NickParsons Yep, thanks for catching the missing the `return`.  And yes, agreed completely on the promise resolving once, which is one of the reasons I don't think this is the right structure for the question.  But, I thought I'd mention this async/await stuff as the person is clearly learning, and hitting on this concept a little bit.

Comment: Now that you have the `return`, why the `await` in `return await ...`?  In fact, you can remove the `async` keyword and the `await`.  I try to teach people (particularly beginnings) away from `return await` because it makes them think the function is returning a value when it's not - it's returning the promise and the `await` is of no value.

Comment: @jfriend00 Purely code style.  Normally in a function like this, I'll have several awaits, and I like to keep it consistent rather than showing that I'm returning the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have kinda found the OOP solution for this (it is not the best):

```
class ConnectionHandler {

init() {
  this.listenForConnections();
}

listenForConnections() {
 io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
        //do stuff
        this.newConnection = true;
        this.update();
 });
}

// the update method contains all the logical decisions of a class
update() {
   if(this.isThereANewConnection()) {
    //add connection to list.. or handle the rest of the logic
  }
  //render screen
}

isThereANewConnection() {
   if(this.newConnection) {
    this.newConnection = false;
    return true;
  }
 return false;
}

}
```